# Permission denied appcfg.py on Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to download the source code for my project running on app engine by following https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code, but I keep getting permission denied. I am logged in as the owner of the project.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a read/execution permission problem to the `appcfg.py` or one of its parent directories. Try `python <path_to>/appcfg.py ...` instead.